# Read double from Scanner and print output without altering

Tags: java, primitive, primitive-types

I want to read a double input (say, from Scanner) and print it as is on the console. My double input can vary in precision and scale.

```
public class SampleTests {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 235345345345.234534;
        System.out.printf("%f",d);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
235345345345.234530
```

Expected:

```
235345345345.234534
```

Comment: Your expectations are not reasonable. The double type has finite precision *and* 235345345345.234534 cannot be exactly represented. Have a look at the old-but-still-good [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/238704)

Comment: Ok, I think what you said makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't know the exact scale and precision. Use `%.nf` where 'n' is a number that you expect the precision wouldn't be greater than.

Comment: I tried this - System.out.printf("%.6f",d); Output is still - 235345345345.234530 (which is incorrect)